# $a_n = n^{-2}$, prove that $a_n$ tends to zero.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

So I have a sequence $\{ 1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\dots \}$,  $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$. I want to show that this sequence tends to zero as $n$ increases. This is the proof I have:

Let $\omega > 0$ where $\omega \in \mathbb{Q} $ and let $N$ be a natural number such that $N>\frac{1}{\omega}$. Now for all $n>N$, we have:
$$ 
n^2 \geq n > N \implies \frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{N}<\omega \iff a_n<\omega.
$$
So I've shown that for all $\omega>0$, we always have a term $a_N$ such that all the terms after it are less than $\omega$.

So is the above sufficient? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance and if you want to improve on the tags, please do.

Comment: If $\omega\in\mathbb{Q}$, how is $\frac{1}{\omega}$ a natural number?

Comment: Oh sorry I don't know why I did that, that was supposed to be a bigger than sign.

Comment: Your proof looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have proved that. In mathematics, the limit of a sequence is the value that the terms of a sequence "tend to". If such a limit exists, the sequence is called convergent.

To show that $a_n$ converges to zero, it is enough to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that if $n>N$, $a_n<\epsilon$. So, just pick $N=\lceil\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} \rceil+1$, thus if $n>N$, $a_n< \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell what you intended, though the argument is not quite clear. You may argue this way:

Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $\frac{1}{n^{2}} < \varepsilon$ if $n > \sqrt{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}$; taking $N := \lceil \sqrt{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}} \rceil + 1$ suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to find the $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N^2}<\varepsilon$?

Take $\sqrt{}$ both sides to get $\frac{1}{N}<\sqrt \varepsilon$, then
$N>\frac{1}{\sqrt\varepsilon}$ is needed to reach $\frac{1}{N^2}<\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon>0$ but small as anyone wishes.